# Определение недели по дате

Tags: алгоритм

В ВУЗах расписание пар делится по неделям. Т.е сначала идет первая неделя со своим расписанием, потом вторая неделя со своим, опять первая итд. Подскажите алгоритм, как по дате, и по месяцу узнать номер недели, учитывая дату когда начинается эта самая "первая" неделя?

Comment: Почти во всех библиотеках, связанных с календарями, почти во всех языках есть нумерация недель: 1..52. Берем неделю, проверяем четность, ..., profit!

Comment: Туплю, благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Для дат, принадлежащих одному году, достаточно их чётность номеров недель сравнить [как @Andrey M предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709705/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5#comment1060057_709705). Например, используя [ISO неделю](http://www.proesite.com/timex/wkcalc.htm) в Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import date

def same_week_parity(a: date, b: date) -> bool:
    assert year_number(a) == year_number(b)
    return week_number(a) & 1 == week_number(b) & 1

def week_number(d: date) -> int:
    return d.isocalendar()[1]

def year_number(d: date) -> int:
    return d.isocalendar()[0]
```

Пример использования:

```py
>>> same_week_parity(date(2017, 8, 24), date(2017, 8, 7))
True
```

То есть 7-ое и 24-ое августа принадлежат к неделям с одинаковой чётностью:

```py
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.prmonth(2017, 8)
    August 2017
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31
```

---

Чтобы поддерживать даты разных лет, необходимо прибавить количество недель в текущем и последующих годах:

```py
def same_week_parity(a: date, b: date) -> bool:
     a, b = min(a, b), max(a, b)
     w = sum(week_count(year) for year in range(year_number(a), year_number(b)))
     return week_number(a) & 1 == (w + week_number(b)) & 1

def week_count(year: int) -> int:
    return week_number(date(year, 12, 28))  # last ISO week
```

Пример:

```py
>>> calendar.prmonth(2021, 1)
    January 2021
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
>>> print(*map(week_number, (date(2021, 1, 1), date(2021, 1, 4))))
53 1
>>> same_week_parity(date(2021, 1, 1), date(2021, 1, 4))
False
```

Хотя оба номера недель для 1-ого и 4-ого января 2021 года здесь нечётные, `same_week_parity()` возвращает правильный результат, прибавляя недели из прошлого ISO года (первая ISO неделя всегда 4 января содержит).