# как получить date из строки в формате `YY-MM-DD

Tags: python-3.x, windows

`Python 3 (Win)` Есть `string var` с датой формата `YY-MM-DD` как получить date ?

Comment: у вас сложности строку в date объект преобразовать? Или как имея date объект получить номер недели? Если первое, то отдельный вопрос задайте. Если второе, то см. [Определение недели по дате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709705/23044)

Comment: Сложности с первым я знаю как получить номер

Comment: попробуйте `strptime()`

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, вы можете использовать strftime:

```
datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Или же можно через datetime

```
from datetime import *

def convert_strtodate(date: string) -> datetime:
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_str2date(date: str) -> datetime:
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%y-%m-%d')
```

Функция примет строку формата YY-MM-DD и преобразует в обьект datetime.

Answer (score -2):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
print(today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S")[8:10]) # -> 08
```

Comment: Это ответ на какой вопрос?

Comment: Эникейщик А что я не так понял вопрос ? растолкуй тогда...